# How to use autocomplete="off" in a section tag

Tags: html, autocomplete

So the use of autocomplete="off" within a DIV is very straight forward, but I am making some modifications to an older project where the HTML is all section tags, VS dosen't like it and I would prefer not to re-write all of the code. Intellisense keeps wanting to change it to aria-autocomplete="none". What is the difference and is there a better way to do this? I am applying this to a CC field. Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: `autocomplete` is not a valid attribute of a [`div`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) though...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understood the question but the `autocomplete` attribute is only meant to be used on the `form` and/or `input` tags.